# How to set error label with TextInputLayout in the viewmodel with kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-textinputlayout

I need to do some input validation for my `TextInputEditText` that is wrapped with `TextInputLayout`.

I'd like errors to appear below the line if the input is done in wrong format.

All the logic is done in the viewmodel instead of the view(fragment or activity). But I can't seem to access the view through viewmodel, for instance:
`textinputlayout.setError("error")` doesn't work in the viewmodel
and `layout.findViewbyId(layoutId)` doesn't work in the viewmodel either.
Any idea?

Comment: Why you need to access `Views` in **ViewModel**? Do UI work in `Fragment/Activity`. Remember `KISS` rule. **Keep It Simple and Stupid**.

Comment: I want to set all the logic in the viewmodel according to the MVVM model and use data binding to connect view and viewmodel

Comment: Pass the `View` as a parameter just like we do in `RecyclerView's ViewHolder`.

Comment: It works!! But do you know how to show the error only after the typing, not during the typing?

Comment: set `OnTextChangedListener` for TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 0):

used below code to set error in TextInputLayout..

```
class SpinerActivity :AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.spiner)
    setEdittext()
}

private fun setEdittext() {
    var textError:TextInputLayout=findViewById(R.id.amEt1)
    textError.error="Please Enter Name"

}
```

}

Comment: This is not what OP intended.

Comment: then provide your code to understand and your need.